# Run Visual Studio command line tools in Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2005

In cmd.exe, I would simply run

```
%VS80COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat
```

to set up the environment for running the Visual Studio command line tools (i.e. cl, link, mt, etc.). I wonder how I can set up the environment for running these tools in the Powershell. Sure, it is possible to run batch files using

```
start-process $env:vs80comntools\vsvars32.bat
```

but then the environment would be gone when the process terminates. I have already done some experiments with System.Diagnostics.StartProcessInfo, i.e.

```
$proc = start-process $env:vs80comntools\vsvars32.bat -passthru
$procInfo = proc.StartInfo
```

and then get the environment from `$procInfo.EnvironmentVariables` but this also does not work.

Are there any other ways to set up the environment in Powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) has an `Import-VisualStudioVars` cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

PSCX's `Import-VisualStudioVars` is a large script that tries to duplicate what `vsvars32.bat` does.  The problem there is that keeping them in sync requires effort and can be a source of bugs.

I prefer to rely on vsvars32.bat to do what it does, and import the env. vars. in to PowerShell. I do that with [Invoke-CmdScript.ps1](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/NothingSolvesEverythingPowerShellAndOtherTechnologies.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already considered that Import-VisualStudioVar more or less mocks the execution of vsvars32.bat instead of actually executing it. 

However, seeing that vsvars32.bat is quite stable for a specific version of VS I don't really think that there is a real problem of keeping the results of both options in sync. 

Nevertheless, I will give your proposal a try.

Answer (score 0):

Another option from PowerShell gallery: posh-vs
Makes Visual Studio command line tools available in PowerShell. Supports Visual Studio 2017 and 2015.